# Finding homeomorphism from $D^n$ onto itself sending a non-zero point $p$ to $0$ and sends boundary onto boundary.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $D^n \subseteq \Bbb R^n$ be the closed $n$-disk and let $p \in \text {int} (D^n).$ Does there exist any homeomorphism $h : D^n \longrightarrow D^n$ which sends $p$ to $0$ and sends the boundary $\partial D^n$ onto itself?

If I have two non-zero points $p,q \in D^n$ then I think one can find such a homeomorphism. If they lie on the same line segment passing through the origin then we can scale $p$ down appropriately so that it hits the point $q.$ Then $D^n$ gets shrunked a little but still the image is homeomorphic to $D^n$ and the boundary is mapped onto  boundary and if they lie on different line segments passing through the origin then we can take proper orthogonal transformation to send one line to the other and then scale it down appropriately. But I don't know how to translate a non-zero point to the origin inside $D^n$ homeomorphically so that boundary remains invariant under the process? Would anybody have any idea regarding this? Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not delete your question immediately after receiving an answer.  This is rude to the person who took the time to answer your question, and rude to future readers who might benefit from the question and answer.

Answer (score 0):

For two points $x,y$ in $D^n$, let $[x,y]$ be the line segment from $x$ to $y$.

For each point $b$ on the boundary, can you not just let your homeomorphism $f$ map the segment $[b,p]$ to the segment $[b,q]$? So in the picture below, you'd map red segments to blue ones by:

$$(1-t)b + tp \mapsto (1-t)b + tq$$

[image]

This is certainly a bijection that fixes the boundary, it's just some work to show that $f$ is continuous (the inverse of $f$ is again a map of the same form, so if you can prove $f$ is continuous, you've got that $f^{-1}$ is too).

Comment: Actually I haven't seen that you answered my question. I applied the same idea what you mentioned in your answer. Although I couldn't find an explicit formula for the homeomorphism.